# *.symbols.nupkg file generated when publishing a .*nupkg file

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, nuget, nuget-package

I'm using **TFS2012** to publish a **nuget package** of a C# Visual Studio 2012 project. In this solution are many projects which I can successfully publish to the specific repository. For one project, which I added yesterday, the publisher creates the `*.nupkg` file as usual, but also creates a `*.symbols.nupkg` as well.

I cannot figure out, which setting in the project may cause this issue.

***.nuspec-file of the project:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package>
  <metadata>
    <id>xxx.xxx.xxx</id>
    <version>0.1.1</version>
    <title></title>
    <authors>xxx</authors>
    <owners>xxx</owners>
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <description></description>
    <releaseNotes>
      - first release
    </releaseNotes>
    <copyright>Copyright 2016</copyright>
  </metadata>
  <files>
    <file src="bin\$configuration$\$id$.pdb" target="lib\net40\" />    
  </files>
</package>
```

**The result in the repository looks like this:**

> File 1:    xxx.xxx.xxx.0.1.1.nupkg
>
> File 2:    xxx.xxx.xxx.0.1.1.symbols.nupkg

**But it should look like this:**

> File 1:    xxx.xxx.xxx.0.1.1.nupkg

---

**EDIT 1:**

I use the external Tools of Visual Studio 2012 to publish to the repository:

Command: `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe`

Arguments: `$(ProjectDir)$(ProjectFileName) /t:Publish /p:xxxPackageSource=\\tfs2012\Repository`

**EDIT 2:**

Furthemore I tried to build the package locally and published it to a local directory. Same result

Comment: How are you calling `nuget pack`?

Comment: How do you use nuget pack in TFS 2012? What's the result if you use  nuget pack to package locally? When you create packages with the  -Symbols option, you'll get a symbol package. Check http://docs.nuget.org/ndocs/create-packages/symbol-packages

Comment: @DaveShaw I edited my post

Comment: @Cece-MSFT I packed it locally, and it's the same result

Comment: @rbr94 How did you call nuget pack in TFS? Or you just use TFS to publish the package? It seems your issue is not TFS related.

Comment: @Cece-MSFT You are right. That's a "project-based" problem. I only use TFS as a repository to publish the project to.